# Telling TextEdit to quit without bringing up the save dialog in Applescript

Tags: applescript

Here is a little test program in applescript:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "Stuff goes here"
delay 1
tell application "TextEdit" to quit
```

I want TextEdit to quit without bringing up the "Do you want to quit without saving" dialog AKA quit without saving.

Is there a way to use something like `killall` in applescript or use shell commands?

Comment: See answer from adayzdone. Just wanted to add that this also works with documents, like "close document 1 without saving".

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to quit saving no
```

Answer (score 0):

To close the top-most TextEdit window, you can try this AppleScript:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to close window 1 saving no
```

When paired with a hotkey launcher like Alfred 4, I find this snippet useful to close a TextEdit window without being interrupted by the save dialog.

---

Another tip to less-painfully close a TextEdit save dialog is to speed up the animation time.  In the Terminal, run this command to change the app's animation setting:

```
defaults write -app textedit NSWindowResizeTime .001
```